Android ndk-some/ip error : Port configuration missing for [1234.5678]. Service is internal
I am trying to run the ndk-someip example using the Ethernet interface.

I have set the IP address, port number, and multicast address, but this problem still appears.

Port configuration missing for [1234.5678]. Service is internal.


the error indicates an issue with service discovery or configuration in your application.
